# Should I explain to my team a facial scar due to surgery?

Tags: communication, united-states, leave

I recently had a minor surgery and biopsy done on my face. This is obviously visible and hard to conceal.

Depending on biopsy result, further treatment may be needed. My role interfaces with both internal and external clients.

**Should I tell my colleagues how the face scar / wound came to be?**

If biopsy results are bad, should I wait until I know of them or proactively notify my manager that I may need medical leave?

Comment: Do you want to keep it a secret as long as possible or do you want to tell them more about the scar if they ask?

Comment: Not their onions... I would probably say something like "oh, just where they took the bolt out" Frankenstein anyone...

Comment: "You should see the other guy" ;D

Comment: I would make up a fun story that changes once a month or so about my extreme adventures.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you had days off for that medical procedure, I would not explain anything. They know you had a medical procedure, they know you have a scar. Enough said.

If anybody *asks*, especially people that did not know you were on leave for a procedure, just tell them that. Maybe add a little humor and keep it short.

Maybe

> Yeah, thanks for asking. I had a medical procedure last week. Didn't hurt, with all the anaestetics, but don't tell anybody, I'm still working on a cool pirate story to explain it. Getting a well trained pet parrot is harder than it looks. Anyway, that budget we were talking about...

If you happen to need more medical leave, only explain that to a small group that should know and only if you know the details.

Good luck with the results.

Answer (score 4):

You're not required to share any medical information.  Feel free to share as much or as little as you feel comfortable doing.

If that's nothing, practice saying phrases like: "No.", "That's none of your business.", "I don't want to talk about it.", etc.

Comment: But if the OP doesn't say, then people will speculate.  It's human nature.

Comment: @SimonB even if OP gave coworkers everything they were told by their doctor, coworkers would still speculate.  You can't control other peoples thoughts and actions.  All you can do is decide how much you feel comfortable sharing.

Answer (score 2):

If someone asks out of curiosity, then you can explain in whatever level of detail you feel comfortable.  You are not required to volunteer the information (but again, you can, if that's your personality).  If you don't want to talk about it, then don't.

However, if your role is interfacing with external clients, you are expected to look professional.  In some locales, a giant gash across your face may be deemed "unprofessional".  You may want to proactively speak with your manager to determine how they would like to go about you interfacing with clients.  If they say it's fine, then you don't have to feel embarrassed or self-conscious about it, and that might be a good conversation to have.

As for requesting medical leave, I like to do that as soon as possible.  Medical leave is (in many locales) something that is legally protected, and you should be able to negotiate something with your company so you still have a job after your procedure (if not, then speak to a lawyer ASAP).  While it's not required to give them advance notice, I like to do so because it allows my boss to prepare project schedules in advance; if my boss has promised a project that I'm on for a certain date, and then I take a bunch of leave in the middle, then he looks bad to his manager.  The more notice you give your boss, the easier it is for him to schedule projects and handle issues in advance.